# How to track a androids location using phone number?

Tags: geolocation

Okay so my phone was stolen and is off locations off whatever can't track. But I do know who stole it and I do have his number is there a way to track his phone?

Comment: There is no way to track his location using just a phone number, unless you are law enforcement or a hacker. If you know who it is, and you have proof, why don't you report him to police?

Comment: Cause we used to be real close and I don't want to get him in trouble he is just going through a hard time I just want my stuff back the phone he took is a moto z force

Comment: A court order is required to track a cell phone by phone number/IMEI number, and must be requested by law enforcement... Otherwise, no. And that "hacker" thing isn't real, hackers can't track a cell phone by it's number, that is just in movies and on TV.

Comment: @acejavelin by hacker I could mean any level of hacking which includes hacking the NSA system (good luck with that...)

Answer (score 0):

There is no way for a law abiding citizen to track the location of a phone by using the phone number.

Your options are to report the theft to law enforcement and see what they can do. Or contact the person on your own, and hope they give it back.

Both options will work better if you have some proof that this person stole the phone.

---

(I don't want to let you down, but the chances of law enforcement putting too much effort into a lost phone, are very small. They will most probably not be able to go as far as getting a warrant to search for the location of the thief, as pointed out by @acejavelin in a comment)

Comment: To be honest, unless the phone was used in relation to committing a felony or in the hands of a suspected felon, the chances that law enforcement will get the OK from a prosecuting attorney to request a court order to locate the device is slim to none. I have worked for a regional carrier in the past, you would be surprised how little this happens, in 10 years I think we only saw a court ordered locate once and that was because a possible child abduction if I recall correctly. Maybe it's different where you live, but a stolen phone is pretty low on LE's priority list.

Comment: @acejavelin agreed. That's why I said "and see what they can do" more about getting the list phone and not tracking the person. But yes, a lost phone is not something they'll going to put too much work into, if any..